# Парсинг цвета с помощью Html Аgility Pack

Tags: c#, веб-скрейпинг

Требуется добыть значения цвета с палитры сайта [color.adobe.com](https://color.adobe.com/ru/Copy-of-Copy-of-Picture-book-color-theme-10243256/).

Вопрос. Как сформировать x path, для получения значений  (style="background:" " в блоке themeBox)? и вывести в result?

Пример кода в редакторе скриптов grasshopper.

```
string source = (new System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadString(url);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(source);

//HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.GetElementbyId("color");
//HtmlNode bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='color']");

DataTree<string> result = new DataTree<string>();


GH_Path path = new GH_Path();

{
  result.Add(bodyNode.InnerText.Trim(), path);
}

A = result;
```

Comment: В начальном html нужных вам значений нет. Они появляются в результате работы JavaScript'а. Следовательно, нужно использовать что-то наподобие `WebBrowser`, `WebKit` или `Selenium`.

Comment: Изобретаете сложный велосипед. У Adobe есть Api, отправьте верный запрос и получите данные. [Вот](https://i.imgur.com/VaJsQzA.png) к примеру ответ, который выдается пользователю в браузере и там видны все ваши цвета (выделил). Ссылка на API если что - `/api/v2/themes/10243256?metadata=all`